# Header display in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, apache-fop

I've been working with FOP 1.0 and I have the following problem:

```
<fo:layout-master-set>      
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4Page" page-width="595.44pt" page-height="841.68pt" margin-top="0.5cm" margin-bottom="0.5cm" margin-left="0.5cm" margin-right="0.5cm"  >
        <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" extent="0pt" margin-top="145pt" margin-bottom="225pt" /><!--36pt 36pt 70.5pt 36pt-->
        <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before" extent="150pt" />
        <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="220pt" /><!--extent="270pt"  145pt-->
        <fo:region-start region-name="xsl-region-start" extent="0pt"/>
        <fo:region-end region-name="xsl-region-end" extent="0pt"/>                   
    </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
```

But when I have this header:
[image]

if I add enough items for another page this happens:
[image]

Is there a way so that when the new page appears it doesn't overlap the other text?
i have uploaded the file to [drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YqOD2pqhF4LMys5bzbNbuLVVOdUZkPd4)

Comment: Why do you have `extent="0pt"` on your `fo:region-body`? I think this attribute is not allowed on `fo:region-body`.

Comment: The xsl was initially made with a program that had an interface similar to MS Word that generated the xsl, so when it was created it had a lot of unnecessary fields and used attributes that weren't supported in FOP 1.0.

Comment: It is quite a while since I did xsl-fo last time. In your case you define the page master as shown, then you add content until the document has 2 pages and on the second page only the header is overlaped with content?

Comment: It's the body that overlays the header, in the next page it moves up and hides its bottom content.

Comment: I did a quick test, used exactly the page definition from your question and created a pdf. I did not insert any header oder footer, but **the text flow respects the defined extents on all pages**. So if your content has different margins from page to page, this is strange. However, I used Apache FOP 1.1 since it is integrated in my XML editor.

Comment: Well, that's weird. Maybe it's because I am using FOP 1.0 and there's a bug with the page definition?

Comment: Can you post the complete FO document in your question? Since you only posted the page master, it could be a problem in another part of the document.

Comment: No, the document it's too large to post it. And Google Drive doesn't letting me upload the file to share the link here.

Comment: Then you could reduce the document to just the size that still shows the problem (2 pages) but has removed all stuff not relevant to the problem

Comment: I uploaded it to my drive and shared the link in the question.

Comment: Drive says that the folder no more exists or I don't have access to it